# Make Javascript NOT parse the IMG SRC attribute

Tags: javascript, dom

What I want to do is to add an attribute to the img tag. The Problem seems to be that Javascript or the browser just rectifies what it sees, but it is crucial that it does not try to rectify my input. The code is from a Magento Store and is actually a placeholder for the actual image.  My expected result is to have the same SRC going IN and OUT.

Here is shortened code demonstrating the problem; the full example is at JSFiddle at the bottom:

I have a textarea (id=textr) with the following code:

```
<p><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" 
title="video icon" alt="video Icon" src="{{media 
url="wysiwyg/Siegel/videoicon.jpg"}}" /></p>
```

When I create a parsable DOM content out of it with:

```
var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
    el.innerHTML = document.getElementById("textr").value;
```

and want to find all the images like so:

```
var totalimages = el.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for(var i = 0; i < totalimages.length; i++){
        console.log(el.getElementsByTagName('img')[i].getAttribute("src"));             
    }
```

I get:

```
src="{{media url=" wysiwyg="" siegel="" videoicon.jpg"}}"=""
```

instead of:

```
src="{{media url="wysiwyg/Siegel/videoicon.jpg"}}"
```

The complete code can be found here to test: https://jsfiddle.net/763wf9fy/

What to do here? I have the same problem when I try to parse it with PHP and I really do not want to start with regular expressions to handle this.

Comment: That is invalid HTML.  You need to escape the attribute.

Comment: Yes it is, but that is what i get! So the solution would be to replace all " with ' inside a html tag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace inner double quotes with single quotes.Change

`src="{{media url="wysiwyg/Siegel/videoicon.jpg"}}"` to

```
src="{{media url='wysiwyg/Siegel/videoicon.jpg'}}".
```

or you can replace the outer double quotes with single quote

```
src='{{media
url="wysiwyg/Siegel/videoicon.jpg"}}'
```

Comment: Yes, it very well may be, but that is what i get and have to work with, hence the question that javascript does not rectify it!

Comment: Thanks brk, but it does not solve my Problem as already stated. I have to work with the input which is there.